# Why do solar cells need to be square-shaped?

Tags: energy, material-science, solar-energy

There were circular solar cells 30 years ago. Why do we have square-shaped solar cells now? Why square?

Furthermore,

Why do monocrystalline solar cells have rounded/cropped edges?
[image]

Comment: Try packing circular cells into a roof panel.  Now try packing rectangular ones.

Comment: If you are asking why the illustration shows "Mono" cells that have beveled corners, while the corners of the "Poly" cells are not beveled, I don't know the answer, but I can _guess._ I guess that beveling the corners is a compromise between a circular cell that uses all of the wafer but doesn't pack well, and a square cell that packs efficiently, but wastes part of the wafer. If manufacturing the polycrystalline wafers is enough less expensive than manufacturing monocrystalline wafers, then maybe they aren't bothered so much by the fact that part of the wafer is wasted.